# alternative solutions for Static Methods And Singleton in java database

Tags: java, android, database

i Want to make a class and some methods in that class which interact with database.
Many other classes Should call that methods.

Q1:is it possible to create only one instance of that class for others ?

Q2:Can i give methods as Static?

Q3:Is there is any alternative solution for static and singleton for java database?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used singletons in Java yet.  However, there's a pretty good discussion on the subject at [http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaSingleton](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaSingleton.)

Basically, you will make your constructor private along with a private static final instance variable.  Then you will need a public static getInstance method that returns your instance.  It gets a bit more complicated if you need to be thread safe, so read the linked article.

Comment: Please fix the URL. Trailing dot.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an enum with a single variable INSTANCE like below:

```
public enum EmployeeDAO {
INSTANCE;

static{
    //Initialize connection info etc.
    init();
}

private EmployeeDAO(){
    //Constructor stuff
}

public Employee getEmployeesById(int id){
            //Replace this with your data retrieval logic
    return null;
}

public Employee getDeadBeatEmployees(){
            //Replace this with your data retrieval logic
    return null;
}

public Employee getAllStars(){
            //Replace this with your data retrieval logic
    return null;
}

public static void init(){

}
```

}

```
public class Employee{}

public class SillyCanuck{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    EmployeeDAO.INSTANCE.getEmployeeById(5);
}

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? This absolutely compiles. INSTANCE is the enumerated singleton and would never be referenced from within this class. There is no trick here. Its no different than declaring a    'static final instance' in a regular java class with the exception that it has compile time guarantees that there can never be more than one instance. Furthermore this example has nothing to do with serialization.

Comment: Agreed. This is interesting way of defining a singleton. And it does have a benefit for serialization (traditional singleton may end up with multiple instances after de-serialization). The only thing I dislike is static{} block: makes it a pain to test; singleton though is always a pain to test.

Comment: Can you check out the wikipedia article on singleton pattern and refer to "the Enum-way" section then reconsider your -1 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_Enum-way. I don't think I'm propagating misinformation, just providing an alternate implementation strategy. DeeP should consider his situation and choose the best solution.

Comment: I would assume you'd delegate your static block implementation to a thoroughly tested static method. And you could test everything by simply instantiating the class in a unit test.

Comment: There does that make you happy